# Find the tick increment value of an equity

Tags: equities, tick-data, nasdaq, nyse, tick

Is there any resource containing the **tick increment values** of `NASDAQ/NYSE` equities (`.0001`, `.01`, `.05`), or way to programmatically determine it (rule or formula) ?

Answer (score 2):

The way I managed to solve this was by scrapping the broker website and compile a list containing  `Symbol`, `Primary Exchange`, `Tick Increment`, `ISIN`, `CONID`, `ASSETID` of 6589 Equities from **NASDAQ**, **NYSE** and **AMEX**.
   Here's a [gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/x011/f43cb959845fcc24aad6ab18325c49b0/raw/834391b6a822419e86ee793ad5f16bbe354429c9/Interactive%2520Brokers%2520Equities%2520(NASDAQ,%2520NYSE,%2520AMEX)%2520-%2520Symbol,%2520Primary%2520Exchange,%2520Tick%2520Increment,%2520ISIN,%2520CONID,%2520ASSETID.txt) of the list:

Answer (score 2):

http://tsp.finra.org/finra_org/ticksizepilot/TSPilotSecurities.txt

The relevant field being "Tick_Size_Pilot_Program_Group", Gx or C categorization. There is no formula to determine this as this rule is new, on a trial basis and the participating listings aren't chosen completely objectively. It's designed to help market making firms at the expense of retail traders.

Answer (score 1):

From a feed perspective, you can take a look at the feed spec, it should be mentioned among descriptions of the data types e.g. fixed point integer with 4 implied decimal places and be applied across all symbols. This should be universal so you could hardcode it.

Thereafter, you can look up the MPV in the rule books - see this answer: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/32383/4660 This would again be hardcoded.

Then, you would want to adjust this for the tick pilot: here's the lists for [NYSE](ftp://ftp.nyxdata.com/Tick_Pilot/Tick_Pilot_Historical/) and [NASDAQ](ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/files/ticksizepilot/Historicalfiles/). This is the part where you would parse and programmatically determine the tick sizes.

Comment: The linked files only specified a part of the total equities traded on both exchanges, I need more. tks anyway!

Comment: Also, the rules presented on the answer you linked to, miss symbols that  trade in 0.05 increments